# Size of a SAS dataset is increasing on using a where clause

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I have a SAS dataset sized close to 20 GB,
I am trying to use a where clause but am unable to do so as the size of the dataset is swelling up and I am getting as error stating: SAS file is full.
When I last looked at the dataset being created in the library the size was close to 45GB.
My code is:

```
data fin2;
set fin;
where segment = "a";
run;
```

segment has 2 possible values a and b (a is close to 50% of the rows)

can anyone tell me what is happening and why is the size of dataset increasing.
I tried doing this with an if command also but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you provide creates new dataset `fin2` keeping existing dataset `fin` untouched. So I assume you're not happy that `fin` has 20GB and `fin2` has 45GB.

I expect `fin` was created earlier, is not stored in WORK library and **has** some compression option enabled. To verify, check output from:

```
proc contents data=fin;run;
```

Contrary, I expect the compression for `fin2` is **not** enabled.

To decrease size of `fin2` table try doing this with `char` or `binary` compression option:

```
data fin_segment_a (compress=char);
set fin;
where segment = "a";
drop segment;
run;
```